# How big does the percent uncertainty has to be to become meaningless?

Tags: error-analysis

How big does the percent uncertainty has to be to become meaningless? Is there a particular percentage (like 50%)?

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningless"? Whether any particular uncertainty is "unacceptable" depends highly on the context.

Comment: 2% error when traveling to another city is practically insignificant. 2% error when trying to land on Mars is very significant.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on ACuriousMind’s comment about the importance of context.

Uncertainties are meaningless in isolation. The purpose of an uncertainty is to allow us to judge the agreement between two (or more) evaluations of the same quantity.  For example, the two evaluations can be two measurements, a measurement and a theoretical calculation, or a measurement and a constraint. Both evaluations must have an associated uncertainty for the comparison to be meaningful, but often one of the uncertainties is negligible, e.g. when comparing an undergraduate lab measurement of a physical quantity with a literature value that has tiny uncertainties.

Sometimes a 100% uncertainty is meaningful, sometimes a 0.0001% measurement is of little use. For example, if are making a measurement that requires the background to be less than 100 (in some units) and you measure the background to be 1±1, then the measurement is very meaningful and you are happy.  On the other hand, if you want to contribute to the investigation of the discrepancy between the measured (0.00116592091±0.00000000087) and theoretical (0.00116591804±0.00000000051) values of the muon magnetic moment, then your team's new measurement should have an uncertainty less than 0.0001% to be helpful.

One situation of special interest is when the purpose of the measurement is to decide whether something exists. A  variant of your question, i.e. whether there is some standard “statistical significance” that is meaningful for claiming a discovery, has befuddled much of the scientific world.  Outside physics, new effects have often  been claimed to exist when their nominal statistical significance is “p<0.05”, which corresponds to 50% uncertainties for two-sided  significance of a simple one-parameter Gaussian likelihood distribution.  This naïve but very common belief that “p<0.05” is meaningful has – when combined with selection and publication biases – lead to reproducibility crises across life and social sciences. In particle physics the significance is expected to be “5 sigma” before a discovery claim is made, which corresponds to 20% uncertainties in the simplest idealized one-dimensional Gaussian case, but which in real research measurements can be very complicated to assess.

Comment: Your last sentence is strange. Uncertainty and significance are completely unrelated. There's no relationship between a 20% error and 5-sigma significance/confidence.

Comment: @Mark H Not wanting to confuse the questioner with  complexities such as non-Gaussian uncertainties, multi-dimensional parameter spaces, and look-elsewhere effects, I did simplify. Thank you for the comment; I have edited the last paragraph.   I do not understand your statement that uncertainty and significance are completely unrelated. For a simple measurement, the traditional significance is calculated from the likelihood distribution associated with the uncertainty in the measurement. Even for searches with large trials factors, local uncertainties constrain any global significance.

Comment: Maybe I have this wrong, but I'm remembering the Higgs boson discovery. The uncertainty in the mass of the particle was less than 1%, while the significance was 5 sigma.

Comment: @Mark H Yes, I wondered if that could be a source of confusion. The abstracts of both ATLAS and CMS Higgs discovery papers give the > 5 sigma significance of the signal but only the value and uncertainty for the mass, which is indeed not directly related to the significance.  (The significance depends on the signal being inconsistent with background, not that the mass is non-zero.) You have to dig into each paper to find the signal strength parameter that is more closely related to the significance, and its uncertainty/value ratio is about 20%.